# Cleaning up and Backup / Migrating existing Unity project into new one or another PC

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wish to copy my existing Unity project into a new blank Unity project. It appears all the object references and many scripts are not configured properly/present in the Hierarchy in my scenes.

I only copied my assets folder/package.json into the new Unity project, because the rest of the files are dirty and have cached a lot of useless information.

*Where are the files, detailing the scenes data located?* I want to copy that over so I can run my scenes with all the object references, and scripts set onto the correct game objects.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Before starting always make Backups - you never know!

---

### Cleaning Up / Migrating as a project folder

In general you will always need the folders

- `Assets`: Contains all the assets like your scripts, scenes, prefabs, 3D models, textures, sounds, materials, etc
- `ProjectSettings`: Contains project settings like e.g. physics, lighting,etc
- `Packages`: Contains a `manifest.json` describing which packages should be installed as dependencies and a `packagelock.json` with further information of the currently installed packages like e.g. their current dependency nesting levels and exact versions/git branches etc

(*state Unity 2019 - relevant folders/files might change between versions*)

All the rest you can basically delete and Unity will recreate/recompile them when you open the project again.

Also see [Behind the Scenes](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.2/Documentation/Manual/BehindtheScenes.html) (for newer Unity versions refer to [Using external Version Control](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html) instead)

> When backing up a project, or adding a project to a Version Control Repository, you should include the main Unity project folder, containing both the **Assets**
> and **ProjectSettings** and **Packages** folders. **All the information in these folders is crucial to the way Unity works**.

**For me** also some of the `Library/*.asset` files make sense to keep .. they store e.g. the build settings, target platform etc. so I don't have to configure them / switch platform from scratch every time I "reset". It's up to you of course if you want to do this as well.

---

You can also use any other version control system ... or of course also remove according folders and files manually but I always use [`GIT`](https://git-scm.com/) for my projects - even if it is only local or even once for cleaning up before zipping the project as a backup ;)

Also refer to [Using external version control systems with Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html) for some general information about the setup for version controlling your project(s).

So when I want to clean up a repository before coping it I usually use the following as `*.gitignore` (it is very basic - for a more complete and constantly updated version see [the one on Github](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore) !).

Everything listed here can basically be deleted and will be re-compiled the next time you open the project in Unity. (Lines starting with `!` are exceptions I added because as said for me it made sense to keep those as well.)

```
# This .gitignore file should be placed at the root of your Unity project directory
#
# Get latest from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore
#
/[Ll]ibrary/
/[Tt]emp/
/[Oo]bj/
/[Bb]uild/
/[Bb]uilds/
/[Ll]ogs/
/[Uu]ser[Ss]ettings/

# MemoryCaptures can get excessive in size.
# They also could contain extremely sensitive data
/[Mm]emoryCaptures/

# Recordings can get excessive in size
/[Rr]ecordings/

# Uncomment this line if you wish to ignore the asset store tools plugin
# /[Aa]ssets/AssetStoreTools*

# Autogenerated Jetbrains Rider plugin
/[Aa]ssets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*

# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/

# Gradle cache directory
.gradle/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
*.mdb
*.opendb
*.VC.db

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.pdb.meta
*.mdb.meta

# Unity3D generated file on crash reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.aab
*.unitypackage
*.app

# Crashlytics generated file
crashlytics-build.properties

# Packed Addressables
/[Aa]ssets/[Aa]ddressable[Aa]ssets[Dd]ata/*/*.bin*

# Temporary auto-generated Android Assets
/[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa.meta
/[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa/*
```

and as said for me personally it sometimes makes sense to add

```
# keep the *.asset files from Library
!/[Ll]ibrary/*.asset
```

If not done yet first initialize the repository running

```
cd your/project/root/path
git init
git add .gitignore *
```

this will show some warnings for every file that is listed in the `.gitignore` but you can ignore those warnings. It only says something similar like

> You are trying to add an ignored file to the commit and it will be skipped

than run

```
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

to make your first commit.

Now finally you can simply run [`git clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean#Documentation/git-clean.txt)

```
git clean -xfd
```

which removes every file that is **not tracked** (so be sure to have always all files you **want** to keep at least staged (`git add`) or better commited first) or would be ignored by the `*.gitignore`.

> [**-f**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean#Documentation/git-clean.txt--f)
> If the Git configuration variable clean.requireForce is not set to false, git clean will refuse to delete files or directories unless given -f, -n or -i. Git will refuse to delete directories with .git sub directory or file unless a second -f is given.
>
> [**-d**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean#Documentation/git-clean.txt--d)
> Remove **untracked** directories in addition to **untracked** files. If an untracked directory is managed by a different Git repository, it is not removed by default. Use -f option twice if you really want to remove such a directory.
>
> [**-x**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean#Documentation/git-clean.txt--x)
> Don’t use the standard ignore rules read from .gitignore (per directory) and $GIT_DIR/info/exclude, but do still use the ignore rules given with -e options. This allows removing all untracked files, including build products. This can be used (possibly in conjunction with git reset) to create a pristine working directory to test a clean build.

If unsure you can also add a

> [**-n**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean#Documentation/git-clean.txt--n)
> Don’t actually remove anything, just show what would be done.

---

Note If you already had a `.git` repository but added / edited the `.gitignore` afterwards also refer to [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

---

### Migrating using UnityPackage (Assets only!)

Another option for moving scenes or parts of the **Assets** between two different projects is using a [UnityPackage](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetPackages.html). **Note that this will not include any installed packages, settings etc but purely the assets and their asset-dependencies (linked prefab, materials, textures etc)!**

**From your current project [export a UnityPackage](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetPackages.html#ExportingPackages)**

Excerpts from the Docs:

> Use Export Package to create your own Custom Package.
>
> 1. Open the Project you want to export Assets from.
> 2. Choose <kbd>Assets</kbd> → <kbd>Export Package</kbd> from the menu to bring up the Exporting Package dialog box. (See Exporting Package dialog box image
>    below.)
> 3. In the dialog box, select the Assets you want to include in the package by clicking on the boxes so they are checked.
> 4. Leave the include dependencies box checked to auto-select any Assets used by the ones you have selected.
> 5. Click on Export to bring up the file explorer, and choose where you want to store your package file.
> 6. Name and save the package anywhere you like.
>
> HINT: When exporting a package Unity can export all dependencies as
> well. So, for example, if you select a Scene and export a package with
> all dependencies, then Unity exports all Models, Textures and other
> Assets that appear in the Scene as well. This can be a quick way of
> exporting several Assets without manually locating them all.
>
> [image]

alternatviely to step `2` you can also <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> on the `Assets` folder in the `Project View` and find the <kbd>Export Package</kbd> option in the context menu.

**and then in the new project [Import the UnityPackage](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetPackages.html#ImportingPackages)**

> To import an Asset package:
>
> 1. Open the Project you want to import Assets into.
> 2. Choose <kbd>Assets</kbd> → <kbd>Import Package</kbd> → <kbd>Custom Package</kbd>.
> 3. In the file explorer, select the package you want and the Import Unity Package dialog box appears, with all the items in the package pre-checked, ready to install. (See Import Unity Package dialog box image below.)
> 4. Select <kbd>Import</kbd> and Unity puts the contents of the package into the `Assets` folder, which you can access from your `Project view`.
>
> [image]

Alternatively to step `2` and `4` you can even simply drag and drop the `unitypackage` file into the `Assets` folder via the Unity Editor.

Comment: Adding to this very comprehensive answer, when stuff gets unlinked, its a sign that you managed to lost you hidden .meta files, and Unity assigned new fresh IDs to everything. If you make sure you copy assets including the metafiles, and move a version up (its a mixed bag when going down a version) everything should link up

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to do something similar which would apply to the "Move to Another PC" part.

I noticed that my projects are taking quite the amount of space and wanted to clean the proyect. I followed [derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7111561/derhugo) answer recommended "git clean" procedure but using his linked [GitHub .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore) file.

I had to make some changes so it work's on Unity 19.4:

```
# This .gitignore file should be placed at the root of your Unity project directory
#
# Modified from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore
#
# Keep Library Folder
#/[Ll]ibrary/
/[Ll]ibrary/Artifacts/
/[Ll]ibrary/ArtifactDB*
/[Ll]ibrary/PackageCache/
/[Tt]emp/
/[Oo]bj/
/[Bb]uild/
/[Bb]uilds/
/[Ll]ogs/
/[Uu]ser[Ss]ettings/

# MemoryCaptures can get excessive in size.
# They also could contain extremely sensitive data
/[Mm]emoryCaptures/

# Asset meta data should only be ignored when the corresponding asset is also ignored
!/[Aa]ssets/**/*.meta

# Uncomment this line if you wish to ignore the asset store tools plugin
# /[Aa]ssets/AssetStoreTools*

# Autogenerated Jetbrains Rider plugin
/[Aa]ssets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*

# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/

# Gradle cache directory
.gradle/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
*.mdb
*.opendb
*.VC.db

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.pdb.meta
*.mdb.meta

# Unity3D generated file on crash reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.aab
*.unitypackage

# Crashlytics generated file
crashlytics-build.properties

# Packed Addressables
/[Aa]ssets/[Aa]ddressable[Aa]ssets[Dd]ata/*/*.bin*

# Temporary auto-generated Android Assets
/[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa.meta
/[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa/*
```

Basically what I did was to not ignore the entire Library folder and only ignore the following:

```
/[Ll]ibrary/Artifacts/
/[Ll]ibrary/ArtifactDB*
/[Ll]ibrary/PackageCache/
```

### Here's the procedure you should follow:

- Backup your Project just in case.
- Put the supplied .gitignore file on your project's root directory
- Run the following commands:

---

```
# Initialize Repository
git init

# Add .gitignore file
git add .gitignore

# Add the rest of the files
git add *

# Commit changes
git commit -m "Initial Commit"

# Clean all untracked files and folders
git clean -Xfd
```

---

*Notice the -X option is capitalized on the git clean command, this avoids erasing any folder that's empty and untracked.

**To verify everything is fine:**

- Load your Unity Project and check everything is still working correctly
- Run git clean -Xfd once more to clean the project's files that were rebuilt by Unity.

Again, thanks [derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7111561/derhugo) for his detailed answer which was used to make this work on latest Unity releases.

Comment: In general the entire Library folder should be ignored since Unity recreates it dynamically. Me force including some asset files that are e.g. build settings etc is not a general suggestion just a personal preference