# Loading Unity solution with Rider corrupts the project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rider

Whenever I load an existing Unity project in Rider, Unity doesn't make me run/build it, returning blank errors in the console.

I have tried reinstalling Unity and deleting Rider's configuration files.

I also believe the bug may be caused by the "Rider Editor" Unity package not working correctly.

Also, after reloading the Unity project, all of the Unity Scripts associated with the Gameobjects are unable to be loaded.

I found this in the Editor.log:

```
-----CompilerOutput:-stdout--exitcode: 134--compilationhadfailure: True--outfile: Temp/UnityEngine.SpatialTracking.dll
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.9.1.65535 (9d34608e)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

-----CompilerOutput:-stderr----------
/home/rotolonico/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.3.0a5/Editor/Data/Tools/RoslynScripts/unity_csc.sh: line 89: 10933 Aborted                 (core dumped) "/home/rotolonico/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.3.0a5/Editor/Data/Tools/RoslynScripts/../../Tools/Roslyn/csc" /shared /noconfig @Temp/UnityTempFile-35071e8ef485631d5b4eb3ee7f34ec61
-----EndCompilerOutput---------------
- Finished compile Library/ScriptAssemblies/UnityEngine.SpatialTracking.dll



Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.9.1.65535 (9d34608e)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


[ScriptCompilation] Recompiling all scripts because: Reload of assemblies failed
- Starting compile Library/ScriptAssemblies/UnityEngine.TestRunner.dll
- Starting compile Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.ugui.dll
- Starting compile Library/ScriptAssemblies/com.unity.multiplayer-hlapi.Runtime.dll
- Starting compile Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.Timeline.dll
```

I am using:
Unity 2019.3.0a5,
Rider 2019.1,
My OS is Fedora 30 Thirty (x86-64)

The problem also occurs in Unity 2019.2 and 2019.1

Comment: Given the alpha stage for 2019.3 it would be best to report that to unity

Comment: Sure, I just did

Comment: The problem also occurs in Unity 2019.2

Comment: what do you mean by `load an existing Unity project in Rider`? did you previously open it different? It might help to "reset" your project. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56267992/7111561) I explained which folders and files you can savely delete and Unity will rebuild them the next time. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried all of that. I have created a brand new Unity project and loaded the solution with Rider and the "blank errors" still appear, making the code unrunnable.

Comment: @DomenicoRotolo 2019.2 is in beta........

Comment: I have also tried it in 2019.1 later yesterday and the bug still occurs

Comment: Try to update Rider to 2019.1.2?

Comment: I already tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a coincidence or not but it seems like the bug stopped occurring when I upgraded from 4GB of RAM to 16GB. This seems like is completely unrelated, but the bug itself started occurring when I was forced to downgrade to 4GB of RAM due to one bank failing.

Comment: Based on your "answer" it sounds like all you did was restarted unity - sure enough that is what fixed the issue for me.

Comment: No, not really. I have tried literally anything, even uninstalling and reinstalling Unity and found the issue in different versions.

Comment: When you upgraded the ram, did you toss the original 4gb? It may have been faulty.

Comment: Yes, I did so that could be the case