# Weird error: Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.5.0-dev-20359-01 (8da8ba0c)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity 2020.3.22f1 project that was perfectly working at first. However, this error occured after editing and saving one of my scripts in Visual Studio (with no apparent bug in it):

[image: bug]

I don't give details about my script or the project, because it doesn't seem  to relate to the project itself or what I did, as the error appears now in all my Unity projects! I first tried to delete the script that triggered the bug, then I deleted the whole project. I even uninstalled/reinstalled Unity (different versions), Visual Studio and Unity Hub. But it seems that now I'm stuck with this forever.

Does anyone have a single clue about this? I saw one or two people having the same problem on the web, and with no other solution than formatting the hard drive. As I'm not working on my personal computer, I can't do that...I mean, there must be a rational explanation to this bug!!

I downloaded the latest version of Unity (2021.2.2f1), launched a brand new project, and the error now turned to: "The specified path can't be found" (rough translation from french), without more precision...still no idea what it means.

[image: The latest error]

Comment: What you show there does not appear to be an error, just a version statement. Please post the actual, complete message that you get - even if it's in French.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The complete message is exactly what I posted (here in french): "Le chemin d'accès spécifié est introuvable"...and that's it. I can add an image to clarify this in my message.

Comment: There must be some invalid file reference. Please post a repro.

Comment: Thank you again. I added a screenshot to the original message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution from here: [Unity 2019.3.0a7: Microsoft Visual C# Compiler Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56913616/unity-2019-3-0a7-microsoft-visual-c-sharp-compiler-errors)

I don't know how it's related, but it is suggested that the error can be triggered by uninstalling Anaconda and Python (which I happened to do recently), which leads to remaining artifacts in the Windows registry. I then deleted the following item in the Windows registry:

> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command
> Processor\AutoRun

and restarted Unity. Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue, the problem is in an incomplete path

Command line is : "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.0a13\Editor\Data\Tools\netcorerun\netcorerun.exe" "C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.1.0a13/Editor/Data/Tools/ScriptUpdater/ApiUpdater.MovedFromExtractor.exe" "Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\UnityEngine.LocalizationModule.dll_9374ECE80455BEFE.mvfrm" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.0a13\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEngine\UnityEngine.LocalizationModule.dll"
Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path **'C:\Users\damos\project name is missing here\Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\UnityEngine.LocalizationModule.dll_9374ECE80455BEFE.mvfrm'.**

This path is missing the project name between damos ans library

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Many thanks for your response! If I get it correctly, you say that the name of my project is missing in a path, but I don't understand what path you are talking about, and what is exactly the "command line". Sorry about that. Could you be more specific?