# Package manager failing to find dependencies

Tags: unity-game-engine, package-managers

I cannot do anything in my Unity Project, namespaces are not getting resolved in my package manager.

***Full Log:***

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@1.0.11\Editor\Discovery.cs(5,13): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'CodeEditor' does not exist in the namespace 'Unity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@1.0.11\Editor\VSEditor.cs(11,13): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'CodeEditor' does not exist in the namespace 'Unity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@1.0.11\Editor\Discovery.cs(35,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CodeEditor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@1.0.11\Editor\Discovery.cs(14,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CodeEditor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@1.0.11\Editor\VSEditor.cs(30,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IExternalCodeEditor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@1.0.11\Editor\Discovery.cs(62,66): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CodeEditor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@1.0.11\Editor\ProjectGeneration.cs(285,21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ResponseFileData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@1.0.11\Editor\VSEditor.cs(79,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CodeEditor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@1.0.11\Editor\VSEditor.cs(89,70): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CodeEditor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@1.0.11\Editor\ProjectGeneration.cs(371,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ResponseFileData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@1.0.11\Editor\ProjectGeneration.cs(496,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ResponseFileData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@1.0.11\Editor\VSEditor.cs(65,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CodeEditor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@1.0.11\Editor\ProjectGeneration.cs(604,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
```

**Screen dump:**

[image]

**What I've tried:**

I have deleted the cache for the package manager, reset the packages to defaults and reinstalled each, and re-imported assets. Nothing has resolved this issue. I suspect its because some SDK I use is outdated, but everything as far as I'm aware is up-to-date. Is this a Unity Bug?

Comment: Please post console outputs as text formatted as `code` (`{ }` button) **not as image**

Comment: Did you try to delete the `Library` folder? It can completely safely be deleted. Close Unity, delete it and open your project again. Unity will then recompile the `Library` folder. (Make a backup anyway! You never know)

Comment: Btw which Unity version are you using? Not by chance maybe a **beta** (2019.2) or **alpha** (2019.3), right? If this is the case you should go to the latest **stable** version instead which is 2019.1.10 currently.

Comment: @derHugo 2019.1.8f

Comment: Afaik `CodeEditor` was introduced in [2019.2 the beta version](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Unity.CodeEditor.CodeEditor.html) is it possible that you opened your project in another version previously?

Comment: @derHugo possibly, by accident. Would clearing the Library folder fix that?

Comment: you probbaly also would ahve to remove the `Packages` folder and eventually re-import the packages you actually want (afaik visual studio tools as Package was introduced in the **beta**). In my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267842/migrating-existing-unity-project-into-new-one-or-another-pc/56267992#56267992) I explained a way for how do completely cleanup a Unity project folder.