# Unity3d | Can't use any scripts at all (Just installed engine)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So basically, I install Unity, create a project, and add a C# script. That's all. And immediately upon its creation I get this error:
[image]

If I try to assign the script to an object I get the message that the script class cannot be found that you normally get when the class name and file name aren't the same.

I tried installing unity like 5 times different ways and I don't know what it's about.

Comment: How exactly did you install Unity? Try to close Unity, delete the `Library` and `Temp` folders of your project and re-open Unity.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59124556/unity-2019-2-invisible-empty-errors-after-trying-to-build