# Unity3D GameObjects missing, what do i do ;0

Tags: unity-game-engine

Yesterday i did some minor changer in a prefab(just a single object, not related to my grid or tiles), everything was working fine. Today i opened Unity up and my Grid was gone, all the tilemaps were spread out my hierarchy, my ground tilemap dont have tiles anymore. It just broke my project out of nowhere.

this errors are now showing in the console.

-ReleaseAllScriptCaches did not release all script caches!

-Broken text PPtr in file(Assets/Scenes/FirstLevelPrototype.unity). Local file identifier (2117126700) doesn't exist!

-Broken text PPtr in file(Assets/Scenes/FirstLevelPrototype.unity). Local file identifier (7117326848162403673) doesn't exist!

-Object GameObject (named 'Ground') has multiple entries of the same Object component. Removing it!

Comment: i cant even open stuff like Build Settings, project settings....

Comment: Revert to last known good in your source control

Comment: @BugFinder i did, i even downloaded the my previous git commit, that i have worked past that. Same thing happens.

Comment: I would suggest you to first try and delete the Library folder, reopen Unity and see what happens. If also that doesn't do the trick, you could try reinstalling Unity, delete the Library and reopen the project.

Comment: Try to completely [Cleanup your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267842/cleaning-up-and-migrating-existing-unity-project-into-new-one-or-another-pc) or simply clone it as a new repository ... Are you using LFS?

Comment: @derHugo i had to recreate the entire level/scene

Answer (score -3):

You should start using Github. So you can turn back when you make a mistake.