# Suddenly there is so many errors when I open a new Unity project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've started learning Unity recently, and everything was working fine, then I uninstalled Kaspersky internet security, and then I faced up some problems in Windows but I solved it.
Then today I wanted to open an old project in Unity that worked fine days ago, and I have a lot of errors like this

```
Error: Could not load signature of Packages.Rider.Editor.UnitTesting.TestEvent:.ctor due to: Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb' or one of its dependencies. assembly:nunit.framework, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb type:<unknown type> member:(null) signature:<none>
```

about 450 errors like that :)
[image: unity errors]

I tried to uninstall the editor and reinstall it, BUT nothing works.
I also tried to start a new 3D project, and it also ended with the same result.
the unity editor I used is 2019.4.18f1 Personal
Need some help pls :(

Comment: I've not used Unity, so this may not be the overall cause, or even a solution, but notice the text in yellow at the bottom of your screenshot: `Couldn't delete *.meta because it's in an immutable folder`. That suggests the folder is read-only, which is why the editor cannot delete it. Examine the folders to see if they are marked as read-only, and, if they are, make them writable.

Comment: @JohnH Yes the project folder was set to read only. I changed it but when I open the same project "after remove read only property in project folder and all its subfolders" the immutable message return. and when I turn back to check the project folder It was set to read only again :)

Comment: @JohnH I think I found something useful in google about Reverting to Read Only. maybe It's a bug in Windows 10. by the way THANKS :)

Comment: So is this solved? Otherwise try to delete the folder `Library` (or in general [Clean Up Your Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267842/cleaning-up-and-migrating-existing-unity-project-into-new-one-or-another-pc)) before opening it in Unity

Comment: @derHugo unfortunately I had to reinstall a clean version of windows 10, I guess it's a permissions and security problem that caused by Kaspersky. I also find out that there is some leftovers form Kaspersky after uninstalling it.