# How to resolve Unity HDRP will not work until error is fixed problem

Tags: unity-game-engine

Recently me and my team decided to go from GitHub to Unity Collab and when my coworker created unity collaboration the project only works on his computer. When I downloaded it I got a bunch of errors which I was able to resolve except of this one:

> System.Exception: Compute Shader compilation error on platform Metal in file Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition/Runtime/ShaderLibrary/ShaderVariables.hlsl:8: failed to open source file: 'Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition-config/Runtime/ShaderConfig.cs.hlsl' at kernel LightVolumeColors
> HDRP will not run until the error is fixed.
> at UnityEngine.Rendering.HighDefinition.HDRenderPipeline.ValidateResources () [0x00054] in /Users/adrianlorencic/Desktop/Programming/2020/Unity/Island Escape Soul Bonded NEW/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@7.3.1/Runtime/RenderPipeline/HDRenderPipeline.cs:536
> at UnityEngine.Rendering.HighDefinition.HDRenderPipeline..ctor (UnityEngine.Rendering.HighDefinition.HDRenderPipelineAsset asset, UnityEngine.Rendering.HighDefinition.HDRenderPipelineAsset defaultAsset) [0x006d5] in /Users/adrianlorencic/Desktop/Programming/2020/Unity/Island Escape Soul Bonded NEW/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@7.3.1/Runtime/RenderPipeline/HDRenderPipeline.cs:352
> at UnityEngine.Rendering.HighDefinition.HDRenderPipelineAsset.CreatePipeline () [0x00000] in /Users/adrianlorencic/Desktop/Programming/2020/Unity/Island Escape Soul Bonded NEW/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@7.3.1/Runtime/RenderPipeline/HDRenderPipelineAsset.cs:33
> at UnityEngine.Rendering.RenderPipelineAsset.InternalCreatePipeline () [0x00004] in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/RenderPipeline/RenderPipelineAsset.cs:12
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:197)

I am using unity version 2019.4.16f, template is High Definition RP, I imported HDRP through package manager(version 7.3.1 - somehow I can't upgrade to the newest version 7.5.2, there is a display every time I open up unity saying that there is a newer version available). Before moving to Collab everything was working ok but now HDRP suddenly isn't working and this error is displayed over 300 times even if I clear it It always comes back and I don't even press the "PLAY" button.

Comment: `How to resolve Unity HDRP will not work until error is fixed problem` -> Fix the error ^^ Make sure your packages are up to date / are you using the same Unity version? Maybe try and [Cleanup your project folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267842/cleaning-up-and-migrating-existing-unity-project-into-new-one-or-another-pc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reference I could find to this issue is [this](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/compute-shader-compilation-error-is-thrown-when-creating-a-new-hdrp-project) issue tracker entry, stating that updating the package fixed it. As I see you can not upgrade your HDRP package, which is definitely unwanted behavior. You can try these steps:

- Delete and redownload the whole project
- Back up your project and delete the "library" folder in your unity project, it gets auto-created on startup.
- Remove and reinstall the HDRP package
- Check if your Unity Collaborations Host is passing you guys some system-specific files which should be ignored

Comment: Removing and installing the newest version of HDRP package helped. Now I got another error saying that "kernel shape combined not found". This is a part of ocean crest I believe.

Answer (score 0):

to fix the problem for anyone checking this out. right click your shader graph file create a material then add it to your item