# Unity Procject version is "Unavailable"

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash

After Unity crashed, the project version changed to mysterious "Unavailable":

[image: What?]

When trying to select the project's original version (2020.1.10f1), Unity crashes. Here is the log:

```
[1230/173655.494:ERROR:file_io.cc(90)] ReadExactly: expected 36, observed 0
[1230/174605.843:ERROR:directory_reader_win.cc(43)] FindFirstFile: System cannot find the specified path. (0x3)
```

I have a very old copy of the project, but it is SO old that I will need to rewrite literally EVERYTHING. How I can fix that?

Comment: Is there a file in `ProjectSettings/ProjectVersion.txt`?

Comment: @derHugo, yes, but modifying it gives no result

Comment: If it is SO old .. how can it be Unity 2020.1.10f1 ? .. that's doesn't sound super old actually ^^

Comment: @derHugo the backup is the same version, but has practically none of my changes/ i meant that.

Comment: No I didn't indeed ^^ Don't you use any version control such as Git ? What is the content of your project version file?

Comment: @derHugo, I used the unity's one - collaborate. Version file is empty

Comment: Try to just fill the content: add the line `m_EditorVersion: 2020.1.10f1` completely close (and quit) the Unity Hub and reopen it ... I general if you have a Version control you could also just roll it back to the last commit right? (Never used Collab tbh) .. otherwise you could also just try and select a Unity version from the Dropdown and start it

Comment: @derHugo, 1) where should I put it? If in ProjectVersion.txt, it wouldn't do anything. 2) it reloads all projects when you close/open it, no reason to kill it's process. 3) Latest commit is completely fucked, also I can't do that beacuse I need to open the project, but it is impossible to it for now. 4) That just crashes Unity as it tries to upgrade old (pre-5.0) Unity version (that means "Unavailable" version btw) to the one I selected. If current version is not the one you start it with, it will just try to upgrade/downdrade it. No exceptions. That's how it works.

Comment: `2) it reloads all projects when` -> no it doesn't the project versions are only updated after completely killing and opening the Hub .. I know that because I switch branches between two Unity versions almost daily in my job currently ;) `4)` after maybe making a backup I would just go for it .. yes it will state that it will "upgrade" but in fact it would only have an affect if there actually were any old versioned types and assets in use .. if it is not the case it should still just load your project and change the version number. Try to delete the entire library before opening the project

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267842/cleaning-up-and-migrating-existing-unity-project-into-new-one-or-another-pc) I describe a bit which folders can be savely removed without worries .. most of crashes are related to the library being in an inconsistent state