# Unity compile assemblies fails after update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This project is can play in editor,
and build xcode were success before version-update.

I tried lot of methods but always get similar exception
like "Error parsing types of editor assemblies",
"System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException","SBP error error"...etc.

then check the editor log, discover that messages always begin with
"Library/PackageCache/com.unity.scriptablebuildpipeline@1.19.1/Editor/Tasks/BuildPlayerScripts.cs:41", there used a method called "PlayerBuildInterface.CompilePlayerScripts",
so I guess maybe its compile error, but dont know how to fix.

Tried copied error-projects's manifest.json to empty project. it can build success.
But in error-projects tried remove/upgrade/downgrade versions of SBP or Unity, always failed.

---

here is info of editor log:
OriginalVersion = 2019.4.14
UpdateVersion = 2020.3.20

Error parsing types of editor assemblies.
UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility:ExtractStackTrace () (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/StackTrace.cs:37)
UnityEditor.Build.Player.PlayerBuildInterface:CompilePlayerScriptsNative (UnityEditor.Build.Player.ScriptCompilationSettings,string,bool)
UnityEditor.Build.Player.PlayerBuildInterface:CompilePlayerScriptsInternal (UnityEditor.Build.Player.ScriptCompilationSettings,string,bool) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/BuildPipeline/Editor/Managed/PlayerBuildInterface.bindings.cs:88)
UnityEditor.Build.Player.PlayerBuildInterface:CompilePlayerScripts (UnityEditor.Build.Player.ScriptCompilationSettings,string) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/BuildPipeline/Editor/Managed/PlayerBuildInterface.bindings.cs:82)
UnityEditor.Build.Pipeline.Tasks.BuildPlayerScripts:Run () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.scriptablebuildpipeline@1.19.1/Editor/Tasks/BuildPlayerScripts.cs:41)
UnityEditor.Build.Pipeline.BuildTasksRunner:Run (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<UnityEditor.Build.Pipeline.Interfaces.IBuildTask>,UnityEditor.Build.Pipeline.Interfaces.IBuildContext) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.scriptablebuildpipeline@1.19.1/Editor/Shared/BuildTasksRunner.cs:56) UnityEditor.Build.Pipeline.ContentPipeline:BuildAssetBundles (UnityEditor.Build.Pipeline.Interfaces.IBundleBuildParameters,UnityEditor.Build.Pipeline.Interfaces.IBundleBuildContent,UnityEditor.Build.Pipeline.Interfaces.IBundleBuildResults&,System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<UnityEditor.Build.Pipeline.Interfaces.IBuildTask>,UnityEditor.Build.Pipeline.Interfaces.IContextObject[]) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.scriptablebuildpipeline@1.19.1/Editor/ContentPipeline.cs:145)
UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Build.DataBuilders.BuildScriptPackedMode:DoBuild<UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Build.AddressablesPlayerBuildResult> (UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Build.AddressablesDataBuilderInput,UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Build.DataBuilders.AddressableAssetsBuildContext) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.addressables@1.18.15/Editor/Build/DataBuilders/BuildScriptPackedMode.cs:236)
UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Build.DataBuilders.BuildScriptPackedMode:BuildDataImplementation<UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Build.AddressablesPlayerBuildResult> (UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Build.AddressablesDataBuilderInput) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.addressables@1.18.15/Editor/Build/DataBuilders/BuildScriptPackedMode.cs:77)
UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Build.DataBuilders.BuildScriptBase:BuildData<UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Build.AddressablesPlayerBuildResult> (UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Build.AddressablesDataBuilderInput) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.addressables@1.18.15/Editor/Build/DataBuilders/BuildScriptBase.cs:91)
UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Settings.AddressableAssetSettings:BuildPlayerContentImpl () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.addressables@1.18.15/Editor/Settings/AddressableAssetSettings.cs:2148)
UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Settings.AddressableAssetSettings:BuildPlayerContent (UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Build.AddressablesPlayerBuildResult&) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.addressables@1.18.15/Editor/Settings/AddressableAssetSettings.cs:2130)
UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Settings.AddressableAssetSettings:BuildPlayerContent () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.addressables@1.18.15/Editor/Settings/AddressableAssetSettings.cs:2097)
UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.GUI.AddressableAssetsSettingsGroupEditor:OnBuildPlayerData () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.addressables@1.18.15/Editor/GUI/AddressableAssetsSettingsGroupEditor.cs:340)
UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.GUI.AddressableAssetsSettingsGroupEditor:OnBuildScript (object) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.addressables@1.18.15/Editor/GUI/AddressableAssetsSettingsGroupEditor.cs:335)
UnityEditor.GenericMenu:CatchMenu (object,string[],int) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/GenericMenu.cs:125)

Comment: After upgrading the Unity version have you also updated the packages in your project? And besides that I would always kill the `Library` folder and let Unity recreate it when changing versions. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56267992/7111561) I described how you can clean up your project from any temporary generated stuff .. I would do this before opening the project in a new version

Comment: Days ago tried kill the Library, but not work. still got same error. thanks.

Comment: Just to remove the package if you don't need it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the question by tons of delete-Try&Error.

Found there is an "i18N.CJK.dll" in plugins folder cause this problem.
While delete it, UnityEditor, even in UnityBuild or XCodeBuild, would not report anything about it. Until the app on mobile which codes need encode would show some unsupport error.

Delete or replace the plugin's dll from outside (exclude copy from older project's plugin folder) would solve it.
And I found in Windows2020 or Mac2019, the dll has already installed in path
"Unity\Library\PlayerDataCache\Android\Data\Managed" , but in Mac2020, there is empty. Seems while unity auto-created library have some bug in Mac2020? or the dll have version update but name are same...guess. Editor log doesnt work about it, WTF.