# Unity Burst package doesn't have dependencies installed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have installed a new version of unity, and when I open the project I get the following error messages:

```
    Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.6.4\Unity.Burst.CodeGen\AssemblyLoader.cs(29,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BaseAssemblyResolver' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)



    Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.6.4\Unity.Burst.CodeGen\AssemblyLoader.cs(912,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AssemblyNameReference' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)



    Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.6.4\Unity.Burst.CodeGen\ILPostProcessing.cs(11,52): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MethodDefinition' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)



    Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.6.4\Unity.Burst.CodeGen\ILPostProcessing.cs(11,77): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Instruction' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


    Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.6.4\Unity.Burst.CodeGen\BurstILPostProcessor.cs(39,24): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SequencePoint' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


    Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.6.4\Unity.Burst.CodeGen\FunctionPointerInvokeTransform.cs(80,94): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TypeSystem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Among other packages missing.
How do I install all the dependencies Burst needs? Thanks

Comment: Can you open the package manager? Try to uninstall "Burst" etc and install them again. Also whenever switching between Unity versions delete the `Library` folder. It is then rebuild by Unity when you open the project again .. and sometimes there stay some remainders that cause issues .. also see [Cleaning up and Migrating existing Unity project into new one or another PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267842/cleaning-up-and-migrating-existing-unity-project-into-new-one-or-another-pc)

Comment: Thanks, deleting library worked

Answer (score -1):

Go `Window` -> `Package Manager` -> Change Packages to `Unity Registry` -> Search `Burst` -> Click `Install`

If it's already installed and the code needing Burst is in an `.asmdef` make sure your `.asmdef` is referencing Burst