# WARNING: The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is experimental and unsupported -Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I have finished my game and trying to publish in google play but it requested that api should be 31 and above. So I changed the minimum api level and target api level to 31. After that unity confirm that if I wanted to upgrade my Sdk then I click upgrade. After upgrade an error occur when I try to publish the game it says "option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated" so I search google for a solution and found this (btw I have unity version 2020.1.17f)

```
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1846144/how-to-remove-androidenabler8-from-the-project.html
```

so after applying the solution above first I build on apk only It's working fine then I build using build app bundle and create symbol.zip then I encountered an error

```
> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :unityLibrary
WARNING: The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:bundleReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:configureReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:signingConfigWriterRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources FAILED
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
39 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 32 up-to-date

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

second error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  error: failed writing to 'C:\Users\Ric\Documents\Ninja Farm Protector\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build\intermediates\symbols\release\R.txt': The data is invalid. (13).


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

third error

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.17f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.17f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle5.6.4\lib\gradle-launcher-5.6.4.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "bundleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  error: failed writing to 'C:\Users\Ric\Documents\Ninja Farm Protector\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build\intermediates\symbols\release\R.txt': The data is invalid. (13).


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :unityLibrary
WARNING: The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:bundleReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:configureReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:signingConfigWriterRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources FAILED
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
39 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 32 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <3746c56c485a40cda2a56050de658f5e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <3746c56c485a40cda2a56050de658f5e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <3746c56c485a40cda2a56050de658f5e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <3746c56c485a40cda2a56050de658f5e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <3746c56c485a40cda2a56050de658f5e>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <3746c56c485a40cda2a56050de658f5e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <3746c56c485a40cda2a56050de658f5e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <3746c56c485a40cda2a56050de658f5e>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <3746c56c485a40cda2a56050de658f5e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <3746c56c485a40cda2a56050de658f5e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <3746c56c485a40cda2a56050de658f5e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <3746c56c485a40cda2a56050de658f5e>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <c84609c921cb488481d7d8a5fcdf9588>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

Comment: the first looks like a warning not an error though

Comment: @derHugo if it's a warning it will build but this one doesn't :)

Comment: what I mean is I don't think the last two are the result of the first .. since you mention an upgrade of the API level .. have you tried to erase the library and any temporary leftover build files?

Comment: @derHugo which library the old sdk? what do you mean leftover files?

Comment: I mean from a previous build using the previous minimum api .. and I mean the `Library` folder of your Unity Project, it is one of the things that are dynamically created and can be completely removed without concerns .. migt happen that some artifacts of the previous settings are causing issues ... see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267842/cleaning-up-and-migrating-existing-unity-project-into-new-one-or-another-pc) for how to cleanup a Unity project

Comment: @derHugo still the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I upgraded to API 31. I fixed it by changing my gradle version to 4.0.1, like this `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'`
[active this here then go and change the line inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6p4a.png)

Comment: Hi is that all? did you upgrade your gradle to 6.1.1? cause when I change to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1' it says "Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.1.1. Current version is 5.6.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in"

Comment: Install the Unity 2020.3.17f1. because of this version's compatibility with Gradle 6.1.1. 
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade the Gradle to 8.2.2+ and delete enableUncompressedNativeLibs flag.