# Why do I get a Layout error when I open my project in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I got errors while loading my project in Unity:

```
1. Unknown error occurred while loading 'Library/CurrentLayout-default.dwlt'.
UnityEditor.WindowLayout:LoadDefaultWindowPreferences()
2. Failed to load window layout: UnityEditor.LayoutException: Window layout at Library/CurrentLayout-default.dwlt could not be loaded.
  at UnityEditor.WindowLayout.LoadWindowLayout (System.String path, System.Boolean newProjectLayoutWasCreated, System.Boolean setLastLoadedLayoutName, System.Boolean keepMainWindow) [0x00122] in <44c3723143904fb88deebc993c7bb491>:0
UnityEditor.WindowLayout:LoadDefaultWindowPreferences()
3. Unknown error occurred while loading 'Library/expandedItems'.
UnityEditor.WindowLayout:LoadDefaultWindowPreferences()
```

Please tell me how to fix them, because I am new to Unity and this is the first time I encounter such a problem. The only thing I understood is that my Layout was not saved (I set Layout: 2 by 3)

I don't know how to fix it and didn't try to do anything as I don't understand Unity because I'm new to Unity and just learning it.

Comment: Does it happen every time you open Unity or just once? I see it occasionally and just fix my layout and move on. It's just a Unity thing.

Comment: @RetiredNinja This is the first time it has happened to me. I opened my project, and this error appeared. I'm not sure if this error could affect the project, but I think it's better to fix it. It occurred when I changed the layout to 2 by 3.

Comment: It doesn't affect your project at all. The project specific layout is stored in the Library directory that is just a cache of your actual project. You could delete it and Unity will regenerate it when you open the project again.

Comment: Sounds like your had a certain window layout opened but then removed some package / library or editor window type so when Unity now tries to restore the layout and open according editor window it can not find the type .. you might just want to [cleanup your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267842/cleaning-up-and-backup-migrating-existing-unity-project-into-new-one-or-anothe)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Unity. There seems to be no problem because the library folder is recreated when you run the project.