# Unity is crashing whenever I open it

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash

I am trying to open my project to work on my game and it crashes every time i open it, nothing i do fixes it.

I tried deleting the Library folder in the project so it could reinstall the files. After deleting the Library folder the project opened fine without crashing, but when I opened the main scene it crashed instantly. It looks like it is failing to compile shaders or not having enough ram, but I don't know how I can fix that. The last thing I worked on in the project was materials with height and normal maps. Here is the crash log https://pastebin.com/75VW6k0E
`this is placeholder text because there is no code to accompany this link, and it says I need to add code`

Comment: Is the project under version control?

Comment: hmm `Could not allocate memory: System out of memory!
Trying to allocate: 18446744056529682432B with 16 alignment. MemoryLabel: TempOverflow` .. that number looks pretty odd ^^ Try deleting the `Library` and `Temp` folders (or [Cleanup the project from generated stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267842/cleaning-up-and-backup-migrating-existing-unity-project-into-new-one-or-anothe))