# Unity 3D ARcore : MissingTextureException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.XR.ARCore.ArCoreImg+MissingTextureException'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I am working with AR Foundation Version 4.2.8 and AR Core Version 4.2.8. For some reason
I keep getting the below error when I try to build my application

### "MissingTextureException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.XR.ARCore.ArCoreImg+MissingTextureException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.XR.ARCore.ArCoreImg.CopyTo (UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRReferenceImage referenceImage, System.String destinationDirectory) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.arcore@4.2.8/Editor/ArCoreImg.cs:130)
UnityEditor.XR.ARCore.ArCoreImg+<g__EntryParts|16_0>d.MoveNext () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.arcore@4.2.8/Editor/ArCoreImg.cs:156)
System.String.Join (System.String separator, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] values) (at <6073cf49ed704e958b8a66d540dea948>:0)
UnityEditor.XR.ARCore.ArCoreImg.ToImgDBEntry (UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRReferenceImage referenceImage, System.String destinationDirectory) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.arcore@4.2.8/Editor/ArCoreImg.cs:163)
UnityEditor.XR.ARCore.ArCoreImg.ToInputImageListPath (UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRReferenceImageLibrary library, System.String destinationDirectory) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.arcore@4.2.8/Editor/ArCoreImg.cs:171)
UnityEditor.XR.ARCore.ArCoreImg.BuildDb (UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRReferenceImageLibrary library) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.arcore@4.2.8/Editor/ArCoreImg.cs:97)
UnityEditor.XR.ARCore.ARCoreImageLibraryBuildProcessor.BuildAssets () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.arcore@4.2.8/Editor/ARCoreImageLibraryBuildProcessor.cs:37)
Rethrow as Exception:

- 
- 

### Error building XRReferenceImageLibrary Assets/ARProject/Core/Scenes/QuestionAR/ReferenceImageLibrary/QrCodeReference.asset: XRReferenceImage named 'Chicken' is missing a texture.

- 
- 

UnityEditor.XR.ARCore.ARCoreImageLibraryBuildProcessor.Rethrow (UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRReferenceImageLibrary library, System.String message, System.Exception innerException) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.arcore@4.2.8/Editor/ARCoreImageLibraryBuildProcessor.cs:16)
UnityEditor.XR.ARCore.ARCoreImageLibraryBuildProcessor.BuildAssets () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.arcore@4.2.8/Editor/ARCoreImageLibraryBuildProcessor.cs:41)
UnityEditor.XR.ARCore.ARCoreImageLibraryBuildProcessor.UnityEditor.Build.IPreprocessBuildWithReport.OnPreprocessBuild (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.arcore@4.2.8/Editor/ARCoreImageLibraryBuildProcessor.cs:74)
UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces+<>c__DisplayClass16_0.b__1 (UnityEditor.Build.IPreprocessBuildWithReport bpp) (at <31b86d204baf45de8328f2d1261a79f7>:0)
UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces.InvokeCallbackInterfacesPair[T1,T2] (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] oneInterfaces, System.Action`1[T] invocationOne, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] twoInterfaces, System.Action`1[T] invocationTwo, System.Boolean exitOnFailure) (at <31b86d204baf45de8328f2d1261a79f7>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)"

Comment: Have you tried to reset the `Library` (deleting the folder) - it will be regenerated on next time opening the project .. sometimes when upgrading Unity or packages some leftover things cause hickups .. see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267842/cleaning-up-and-backup-migrating-existing-unity-project-into-new-one-or-anothe)

Comment: I usually close Unity and delete all the files in the package cache when I get similar errors and usually works. I think it has something to do with arcore ReferenceImage assest that was causing the error. Solved it . Thanks @derHugo

Comment: only the `PackageCache` might not be enough in some cases where other things are runtime compiled into the Library that also depend on the packages ;) Glad it worked out for you though! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I usually close Unity and delete all the files in the package cache when I get similar errors and usually works. I think it has something to do with arcore ReferenceImage assest that was causing the error. Solved it